# Dynamic added elements double effect after page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have added  dynamic from jQuery in my code, but when I go back one page and return to the page where the 's are added and you press them, they somehow click twice now.

I have tried with an alert('something'); when I click:

```
$(document).on('click', '#products a', function() {
  alert('something');
}
```

And it's shown twice when you return to the page. I have tried

```
$('#products a').remove();
```

When you click the 'Back' button, because I thought all elements where added twice, but that made no difference.

I don't have anything around these lines, maybe I need $(document).ready(); or something with pageinit?

Comment: please post your HTML

Answer (score 3):

This is also known as a multiple event triggering problem and it is common to jQuery Mobile because of its architecture.

There are several solutions to this problem:

#### Solution 1

Best solution would be to use **`pageinit`** to bind events. If you take a look at an official documentation you will find out that **`pageinit`** will trigger ONLY once, just like document ready, so there's no way events will be bound again. This is best solution because you don't have processing overhead like when removing events with off method.

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AAFH8/

This working solution is made on a basis of a previous problematic example.

#### Solution 2

Remove event before you bind it:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).off('click', '#test-button').on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    }); 
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/K8YmG/

#### Solution 3

Use a jQuery Filter selector, like this:

```
$('#carousel div:Event(!click)').each(function(){
    //If click is not bind to #carousel div do something
});
```

Because event filter is not a part of official jQuery framework it can be found here:   http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

In a nutshell, if speed is your main concern then **Solution 2** is much better then Solution 1.

#### Solution 4

A new one, probably an easiest of them all.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        if(e.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        {
            alert('Clicked');
            e.handled = true;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Yerv9/

Working examples can be found **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/)**.

One other thing, don't use document ready with jQuery Mobile, use proper page events instead. Best solution would be to use pageinit which triggers only once, read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.